# Как проверить функцию шаблона HELM на наличие пустых переменных?

Tags: golang, kubernetes, openshift

В helpers.tpl:

```
{{- define "test.template" -}}
{{- $value1 := .Values.testValue1 -}}
{{- printf "%s" $value1 -}}
{{- end -}}
```

В someTemplate.Yaml

```
connect-url: {{ template "test.template" . }}
```

В Values.yaml:

```
incorrectValue: Some
```

Когда я запускаю `helm template .` с заведомо некорректными параметрами получаю следующее:

```
connect-url: %!s(<nil>)
```

Как можно проверить и принудительно пустить в ошибку если в функции нет корректного значения(или если функция возвращает `%!s(<nil>)` ), что бы предотвратить пустые, незаполненные параметры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Добавлен параметр `required`

```
{{- define "test.template" -}}
{{- required "Value 'testvalue1' is required" .Values.testValue1 -}}
{{- end -}}
```